# Prevent a React unmounting issue within a callback

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component within some tabs. The tabs context provides an API to move between the tabs. When I click a button within one of the tabs, it calls a third party components API to validate some data. That API provides a callback that says whether the data was valid. If the data was valid, I want to move to the next tab (next step). However, doing this causes a general explosion of some sort that seems likely to be me unmounting the third party component within its own callback. The easy hack is to use a setTimeout, but I'd like a more proper way.

Here is a code example

```
const handleOnSubmit = useCallback(() => {
  api.validate(valid => {
    if(valid){
      // oh no, the component will be unmounted within this callback
      moveNext()
    }
  })
}, [api, moveNext])
```

So I did instead something like this with the same problem

```
const handleOnSubmit = useCallback(() => {
  api.validate(valid => {
    if(valid){
      setMoveToNextStep(true)
    }
  })
}, [api, moveNext])

useEffect(() => {
  if(moveToNextStep){
    // nope, same problem
    moveNext();
  }
}, [moveNext, moveToNextStep]);
```

And this is the only thing that "works"

```
const handleOnSubmit = useCallback(() => {
  api.validate(valid => {
    if(valid){
      setTimeout(() => {
        moveNext()
      });
    }
  })
}, [api, moveNext])
```

What's the right way to do this?